# Datepicker in View.Onclicklistener

Tags: android, datepicker, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm trying to setup my date picker in a separate class basically to keep my code clean. My code works when using it on a activity but when I attempt to use it on View.OnclickListener I can't seem to get the context right and I receive a context.getsystemservice error. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

View.onclicklistener

```
public class SelectDate extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


public Context context;
public EditText selectDate;
public SelectDate(EditText selectDate) {
    this.selectDate = selectDate;
}




int year_x, month_x, day_x;
int dateInt;
DatePickerDialog dialog;


@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(selectDate.getWindowToken(), 0);


    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            year_x = year;
            month_x = monthOfYear;
            day_x = dayOfMonth;

            int month = monthOfYear + 1;
            String date = dayOfMonth + "";
            if (date.length() == 1)
                date = "0" + date;
            date = month + date;




            selectDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);
            dateInt = Integer.parseInt(date);

        }
    }


            ,year_x,month_x,day_x);

    // Disable dates in the past
    dialog.getDatePicker().

            setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);


    dialog.show();

}


}
```

Setting the onclick listener

```
EditText selectDate = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editDate);
convertView.findViewById(R.id.editDate).setOnClickListener(new SelectDate(selectDate));
```

Error message

```
android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Trying getting the context from the View v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always the best approach to use the View object available to you.

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Perfect. I have a small issue where the user can pick an older date  which they couldn't when the code was on the activity but that's another problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize value of context field in your class. Instead of context field in your activity you can simply replace it with 'this'.